# Is there a way to configure a repo to recursively download some of its submodules when cloned?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a repo A that is dependent on other repos B & C, I would like to add them to my repo but not store their history or codebase. In order to do that I am trying to create a submodule for each dependent repo (B & C). The problem is that I would like to be able to `git clone` A (without using `--recursive` or `--recurse-submodules`).

```
A is dependent on B and all of B's submodules

A is dependent on C and none of C's submodules
```

My attempt was to change the gitmodules file in A and add `fetchRecurseSubmodules = true` to B & C but that does not seem to be working.

If this is not possible, a complete different way to approach this is welcome!

Thanks

**Update: Just to clarify I would like a solution that is configured in the repo (not locally)**

Comment: "Just to clarify I would like a solution that is configured in the repo (not locally)": that is the point of my answer: there is no way that I know of to configure at the repo level, possibly for security purposes: downloading something automatically is better handled locally, after review, than remotely.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what the security purposes are, if you are already downloading something (this something would already be a potential risk) having it have dependencies on other projects does not seem like a vulnerability

Comment: Anything that downloads automatically something without you having to make the voluntary decision (with `--recurse`) to do so is a security risk. Either through Git itself (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/git-vulnerability-with-submodules/, https://github.blog/2018-10-05-git-submodule-vulnerability/) or through what is downloaded.

Comment: If you trust whatever server/source/developer you are downloading the main repo from, then it doesn't make sense for you to decide the submodules they have also chosen are instead a security risk. How is a vulnerability, a bug, in the submodules-related code any meaningfully different than an unfortunate hole anywhere else in the git client? Even more specifically, nothing of what you linked has anything to with the the stuff that gets recursively downloaded (they were all shortcomings in the parsing of the root .gitmodules file AFAICT).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can avod using a recurse option, but you can at least set it by default with the [`submodule.recurse` config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submodulerecurse):

```
git config --global submodule.recurse true
```

Then a simple `git clone` would be enough to created, initialize and clone *all* submodules of your main repo.

That remains a *local* solution however: anyone else wanting to clone the same repo with a simple `git clone` would have to set the same config first.